# How to reuse a model to relate with multiple models

Tags: database, design-patterns, architecture, foreign-keys

I've worked on big projects before, but I'm trying to improve my best practices, and one thing that I'm stuck on is not to create many models.

This might seem a little bit confusing, so let me put an example:

Let's suppose I have a `Post` model, and an `Answer` model, the answer one relates to the Post in a `One-Many` relationship.

Then, I want to add a `Comment` model, both to `Post` and `Answer`.

I could add two `Foreign Key` `nullable` columns on the `Comment`, to show which model it belongs.

But I could also create `PostComment` and `AnswerComment` models, removing the nullable column, but creating more kind of boilerplate.

Which practice is the best?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I'm assuming the design is primarily to support a transactional application ([OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing)), and not reporting ([OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)).  I'm also assuming that model = table.

There's nothing inherently wrong with having multiple tables, as long as the design makes sense (can be easily supported), can be extended / modified with relative ease (maintained), does not lead to poorly performing queries (e.g. if there's a mismatch between the database schema and how calling applications want to consume its data.

If data is the same, it should probably go into the same table; e.g. if you're dealing with birds then don't have tblHawk, tblParrot, etc - but you you had all animals then sure you'd probably want to seperate them out somehow - tblBird, tblFish, tblMammal, etc - because the data would be too different & too hard to model effectively.

You have answers and posts - I assume these are different enough that having separate tables makes sense?  If so, what about comments to them?  If comments are essentially the same regardless of post/answer then one table, as you described, is probably a good idea.

Also consider the application: if you have separate post/answer comment tables there's more code to be developed and maintained - but it's separate, so more code but possibly more flexible with less complexity.  Using one table will have the opposite affect.  Neither is wrong, but one approach is probably better than the other depending on your situation.